# Android (Java): Programatically adding TextView(s) with weight 1 to a TableRow does not result in TextView(s) of equal width

Tags: java, android, xml

In my Android application, I am attempting to programatically add a `TableRow` to a `TableLayout` in which the `TableRow` has `TextView`(s) of equal weight (1), meaning they occupy the same width. Below is an image showing what I am trying to achieve (I am trying to programatically add the `TableRow` highlighted in red):

[image]

However, below is the result of my code after programmatically adding a TableRow with 3 `TextView`(s) of equal weight 1:

[image]

Below is the XML for the main layout, and the template used to programmatically create the `TextView` of weight 1. The error seems strange, considering that in the template used to programatically create the `TextView`, I specified the weight as 1.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp">
        <TableRow
            android:background="#d6d7d7"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="B"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**table_textview.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.programaticallyaddtablerowtotablelayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Retrieve of the table layout.
        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);

        // Initialize the row to be added to the table layout.
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
        newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // Add the TextView(s) to the row.
        TextView xView = (TextView) createViewFromXMLTemplate(R.layout.table_textview);
        xView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        xView.setText("X");
        newRow.addView(xView);

        TextView yView = (TextView) createViewFromXMLTemplate(R.layout.table_textview);
        yView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        yView.setText("Y");
        newRow.addView(yView);

        TextView zView = (TextView) createViewFromXMLTemplate(R.layout.table_textview);
        zView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        zView.setText("Z");
        newRow.addView(zView);

        // Add the row to the table layout.
        table.addView(newRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    // Creates a View by inflating a template XML layout.
    private View createViewFromXMLTemplate(int layout) {
        return getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: change width = 0dp and add weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do like below to get `weight` over TextView

```
TextView tv = new TextView(v.getContext());
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using setColumnStretchable (int columnIndex, boolean isStretchable)